# Permanently redirect all STDERR (not STDOUT) in a session to a logfile -- like script

Tags: bash, stderr

I want to store in a database all commands that trigger errors and the error output only (stderr) of those commands. As a first step, I'm trying to store the commands and error output (if there is any) into log files in a directory.

I know that you can use pipes to redirect output from individual commands to a file:

```sh
ls -al 2>> /path/to/running/file.log
```

I also know that you can start a script session to save all terminal output:

```sh
script /path/to/running/file.log
```

But I don't want to store the stdout or stdin.

Here is a script that works to do what I want:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

exec_date=$(date '+%F_%T')
$@ 2> "${exec_date}.log"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  rm "${exec_date}.log"
else
  echo "$@" >> "${exec_date}.log"
fi
```

The problem is the user would have to type that in before every command -- I also imagine it's inefficient as hell. Isn't there a simple way to just set the location of stderr to a separate file or something?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `exec`.

```
exec 2>>/path/to/running/file.log
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I knew there had to be a way to do this. I searched forever and couldn't find it. Thank you so much [=